# How do I move to next step after saving step 1 data in multi step forms?

Tags: php, jquery

I am using multi-step form to save person details. I want to save each form separately with PHP post. After saving step one form data I am not able to move to step two and so on. So how should I achieve this?

I have created different fieldset and on next button I am moving to another fieldset with jQuery. I am saving data with form post method into the database.

This is my html code:

```
<div id="msform" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="row" style="margin: 0px auto 0px;">
        <ul id="progressbar">
            <li class="active"></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <fieldset class="fieldset" id="fieldset1">
        <form id="" method="post" action="">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2 mp0" for="nm">Film Course :</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2 mp0" for="nm">Height:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2 mp0" for="nm">Shoe Size:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <select class="form-control" required="" style="text-transform: lowercase;" onchange="yesnoCheck(this);">
                        <option>Select Type</option>
                        <option>4</option>
                        <option>4.5</option>
                        <option>5</option>
                        <option>5.5</option>
                        <option>6</option>
                        <option>6.5</option>
                        <option>7</option>
                        <option>7.5</option>
                        <option>8</option>
                        <option>8.5</option>
                        <option>9</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2 mp0" for="nm">Chest / Breast:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2 mp0" for="nm">Pant Size:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <label class="control-label col-sm-2 mp0" for="nm">Additional Skills:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" id="btn1" name="next" class="next action-button btn btn-success" value="Save & Next" />
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset" id="fieldset2">
        <form id="form2" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-sm-1 mp0 col-6" for="nm">Cycle/Bike Riding:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-6">
                    <input type="radio" name="ocs" class="" value="Yes">Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="ocs" class="" value="No">No
                </div>
                <label class="control-label col-sm-1 col-12 mp0" for="nm">Car Driving</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-12">
                    <input type="radio" name="ocs" class="" value="Yes">Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="ocs" class="" value="No">No
                </div>
                <label class="control-label col-sm-1 col-12 mp0" for="nm">Horse Riding:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-12">
                    <input type="radio" name="ocs" class="" value="Yes">Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="ocs" class="" value="No">No
                </div>
                <label class="control-label col-sm-1 col-12 mp0" for="nm">Swimming</label>
                <div class="col-sm-2 col-12 ">
                    <input type="radio" name="ocs" class="" value="Yes">Yes
                    <input type="radio" name="ocs" class="" value="No">No
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button  btn btn-danger" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn btn-success" value="Next" />
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <form id="form3" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <h4>Portfolio Images </h4>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-6">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input required type="file" name="fileToUpload" multiple data-preview-to="#preview4" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div id=preview4 ></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <input required type="file" name="fileToUpload" multiple data-preview-to="#preview6" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <div id=preview6></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button  btn btn-danger" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn btn-success" value="Next" />
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <form id="form4" method="post">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-sm-12 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-offset-1">
                    <div class="outer-area">
                        <h5 class="form-sub-title"> Project</h5>
                        <div class="gallery-form" id="project"> 
                            <table class="table">
                                <tbody id="TextBoxContainer">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label col-sm-3 ">Project Name</label>
                                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Project Name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </tbody>
                                <tfoot >
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="5" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;border-top:none;">
                                            <button id="btnAdd" type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Add more controls" style=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i>&nbsp; Add&nbsp;</button>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                </tfoot>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button  btn btn-danger" value="Previous" />
            <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button btn btn-success" value="Next" />
        </form>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery:

```
     $(".next").click(function(){
        var current = $(".fieldset:visible"),
            total = $(".fieldset").length,
            last = $(".fieldset:last");
        $(current).next().show();
        $(current).hide();
        // $(current).('form').submit();
        if ($(current).next().is(last)) {
            $(".next").hide();                                      
        }
    });

     $(".previous").click(function(){
        var current = $(".fieldset:visible"),
            total = $(".fieldset").length,
            last = $(".fieldset:last");
        $(current).prev().show();
        $(current).hide();
        if ($(current).next().is(last)) {
            $(".previous").hide();
            //$("input[type='submit']").show();
        }
    });
```

I want to save post data (without using ajax) after every next and move to the next step.

Comment: You can save the data in hidden form fields.

Comment: try triggering click event after saving

Comment: ok @Virushabadoss

Answer (score 1):

I used iframe for it.

**HTML**

```html
<iframe style="display:none" name="submit_frm"></iframe>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e){
    $(this).attr('target', 'submit_frm');
    return true;
});
```